# Stop Python Gtk.Application using Ctrl+C

Tags: python, gtk3

I am creating an application. Previously, I were using `Gtk.Main()` to start my application, and created some hooks to stop the application from the command line using `Ctrl+C`. Now, I have migrated the application to a more "standard" `Gtk.Application`, but can't get it to stop using `Ctrl+C`.

This is a very simple `Gtk.Application`, that when is run from the command line, it can't be stopped using `Ctrl+C`:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

# a Gtk ApplicationWindow


class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    # constructor: the title is "Welcome to GNOME" and the window belongs
    # to the application app

    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Welcome to GNOME", application=app)


class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):
    # constructor of the Gtk Application

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    # create and activate a MyWindow, with self (the MyApplication) as
    # application the window belongs to.
    # Note that the function in C activate() becomes do_activate() in Python
    def do_activate(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        # show the window and all its content
        # this line could go in the constructor of MyWindow as well
        win.show_all()

    # start up the application
    # Note that the function in C startup() becomes do_startup() in Python
    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

# create and run the application, exit with the value returned by
# running the program
app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

Comment: Please put code snippets here and not remote

Comment: I believe this must be either specific to your code or Python. My Perl GtkApplication code ends fine with Ctrl+C.

Comment: Yes, it's specific to Python. The KeyboardInterrupt exception doesn't propagate across main loop iterations, if I remember the reason correctly.

Answer (score 6):

```
import signal
from gi.repository import GLib

...

GLib.unix_signal_add(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, signal.SIGINT, app.quit)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer.  A code-dump is not an answer by itself.

Comment: Best hint so far. I assumed there would be a way to make GLib catch the signal itself but didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with `Gtk 3.0`:

```
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GLib

app = Application()
GLib.unix_signal_add(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT, signal.SIGINT, Gtk.main_quit)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Ctrl+Z to stop the execution of script.

Comment: Yes, but that does not stop the application, only the execution.